# how to write this SQL? specifics inside

Tags: sql

Assume we have a table which records grades of all students of a class. There are two columns among others in the table: 1) student_id, 2) grades, The value of grades is a single letter which can be "A", "B", "C" or "F". How to write a SQL listing all student ids (one student per line) who has never got a "B" grade? Thanks.

PS: Assume we are using MySQL.

Comment: can you post the Input table and output result set

Comment: @Jonathan: I don't think they are necessary for the SQL.

Comment: @ OP - They would make it easier to understand. Like I am assuming that each student ID can come multiple times with different grade. How would I know for sure unless you have sample Input and output result set.

Comment: Assume you've posted the table definitions, sample data, and your own effort to write the SQL, and then asked a specific question about problems you're having with that SQL statement. Also assume that your teacher wants you to complete the assignment yourself, because we're not the ones taking the class, and they want to see your work instead of ours.

Comment: @Ken White: I am not a student studying database. So do not assume anything as if you know everything,

Comment: You're the one that started *assuming* (read your own first sentence). If you want help here, provide the information necessary, show your efforts to solve the problem, and ask a specific question. Until then, this is a lame effort to get someone to do your work for you. You're certainly not someone who knows anything about SQL, which means you're trying to learn it by getting us to do it for you, which means you're attempting to cheat the learning process, and the only reason to do so is to get a passing grade on an assignment. Not an assumption - basic thought. Try it.

Comment: @Utsav: Do you see any student changing his or her student id frequently? It suffices to assume common sense.

Comment: @Ken White: I have provided necessary information here. Those who demand more information only do not know how to answer. For those people like you. It's better to keep silent and give the chance to answer to others.

Comment: This question needs to be closed.

Comment: For those people like you, we need to find a better way of closing questions more quickly, so there is less trash and clutter here. We're here to help those who are willing to put in some effort, not those people who want to pretend to study to get out of school, and then end up being those stupid co-workers we all have to clean up after when their fake degrees get them a job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need a subquery to accomplish this. You'll return records from the table where the student_id is not in the list of students who have received a B.

```
select student_id, grades
from table_name 
where student_id not in (select student_id from table_name where grade = 'B')
```

Comment: Yeah, this works. Thank you. PS: I didn't down your answer (and others), Maybe downed by someone who pretends to be an expert by speaking large words but is unable to answer.

Comment: No problem. In his defense, there are a lot of talented people who spend a great deal of time helping others on this site, but there is a basic expectation that some effort is taken to come to a solution before posting a question. There is also a great tutorial on how to ask good questions that might be beneficial: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks for defending me, but @user5280911 is making assumptions without knowing facts by *assuming* that I was the downvoter here, when in *fact* the only thing I've downvoted is the low effort question that was asked. It seems to be a habit with that user to make assumptions. It's a shame that users (such as yourself) waste time trying to help these leeches.

Answer (score 0):

Use this and sorry, you need to define that student_id can be repeated in table

```
select student_id from table_name where grades in ('A','B','C')
and student_id not in(
select student_id from table_name where grades = 'B'
)
```

Comment: wrong. 1) grades is a single letter, 2)I want "one student per line".

Comment: This would not produce a list of students who never received a B, it would produce a list of students and grades where the grade is not a B. You would still get students in the results who had a B at some point.

Comment: 1) Don't answer low-quality questions that show no effort. They benefit no one here in the future. 2) Don't do homework assignments, because we don't want to be the ones who have to work with these losers in the future. 3) Don't post answers based on information you don't have and therefore can't test. 4) Never, ever say *Try this*, because that's a suggestion and not an answer. Your answer should be definitive, and should explain specifically why it is the solution to the problem - a suggestion to *try* something means you don't know if it will work or not, and that's not an answer.

Comment: Maybe if you define that your student_id can be repeat a student in your question...

Comment: @Ken White: Don't pretended you know by saying some question is  low-quality, That only show your stupidity. Keep silent and learn from others is a better way.

Comment: @user5280911: If it walks like a duck, and quacks like a duck, it's a duck. If it's a crap question, it's a crap question. Does your mommy know you're using the computer?

Comment: @Santiago: Thank you for your comment but, if you design such a table. What will you do?

Comment: Please @KenWhite I recognized my error for a mistake understanding the question, I edit the answer with correct query and  user5280911 after to do a question please try to search how solve your problem

Comment: If i design the table the student_id need to be unique and I will add a new column for asignature